# Using JavaScript in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

I am new to Jade and am struggling to understand how to embed a javascript code inside a .jade file. I am using jade 1.3.0. Lets say i just want to log "script Called' using javascript. Below is my simple index.jade file. When i run this i get an empty html page

```
extends layout

block mainContent
script.
  console.log('Script Called')
  h1 Some Text
  vTitle = title
  table(border = '10' bordercolor = 'red') 
    tr
      td 
        h2 Text1
      td 
        h2 Text2
      td 
        h2 Text3
```

Comment: Did you look at the generated HTML?  That should give you a clue to what's happening.

Comment: The `script.` block needs to be indented to be inside `block mainContent`, or it won’t do anything. (Jade is really bad at this.) You’re also missing a comma between the attributes of the `table`.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is off. Try this:

```
extends layout

block mainContent
  script. 
    console.log ('here')
  h1 Hello
  p This is text
  .hasClass
    .left This is left inside the hasClass wrapper div
    .right This is right inside the hasClass wrapper div
```

Check out the [official jade documentation](http://jade-lang.com/) for proper syntax.